# glibc Linux based

Tags: glibc

I am currently using ubuntu 9.10 with the glibc version 2.11.1-0,
well i am doing a project, that i want to test with the another version of glibc that is 2.5-58, i wanted to know following things regarding this:

How to compile the version of 2.5-58, however keeping the previous version?

How to link the existing programs with the binaries of newer version of glibc?

I would be highly obliged if anybody can help me!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually compile another version of glibc, then I suggest you configuring (`./configure` script run) it with `--prefix` option to install not to /lib, /usr/lib but to /home/mehul/glibc2.5.58test/lib and /home/mehul/glibc2.5.58test/usr/lib

But compiling of glibc is not very easy thing, so another way is to get glibc 2.5-58 in compiled form from other linux and manually copy it to some subdirectory. Then you can override library search path of gcc and recompile your lib with libc from subdirectory.

Or you can use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to override library search path of compiled binary to use older glibc like this:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/mehul/glibc2.5.58test/lib /path/to/your/application
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that that version of libc is used in an older ditribution, you could install that distribution in a chroot/scratchbox/kvm/qemu/livecd or other such system for testing and building. Or there may be some other build farm type solution. Then you'll have an authentic system to test on that will not mess up your up to date one. It'll also be repeatable if you keep that system image.

If this isn't about a specific older release, why on earth would you want to test against a specific very old libc?